# Arabic text from android app to mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, utf-8, arabic

I have some problem with parsing arabic text to mysql database. Here is what I do:

1. Parse text from app to php script

   ```
   String address = ListActivity.urlZapis;
   try {
       address +="?lp=" + detal.lp + "&date=" + detal.date + "&name=" + URLEncoder.encode (detal.name, "UTF-8");
   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }

   try {
   URI uriAddress = new URI(address.replace(" ", "%20"));
   address=uriAddress.toString();
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(address);

   httpClient.execute(httpPost);

   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. in php file I connect to mysql and send data

> $connect = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password",
>   "$db_name");

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Then I see something like this in my phpmyadmin:
name - Ù…Ø§ÙƒØ±ÙˆÙŠÙ ÙˆÙƒÙˆÙ„Ø§Ø±
instead of arabic text.
Collation of mysql is set to utf8_general_ci.
When I enter arabic text by phpmyadmin, everything works fine. It appears in my app correctly, so I am sure there is something wrong with sending it to db.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode your POST as utf-8 and your mysql is also utf-8 . and do not use UTF-8 to create  php script,just use notepad create it default.

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"utf-8"));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse:

right click right-click on your project. Go to Properties-->Resource--->Text File encoding--->other-->UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason why it didn't work!
I had:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");
```

and then

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

which is buggy, cause first I use mysqli_connect and then mysql_query (not mysqli_query).

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
@header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

**Befor**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ") or die(mysql_error());
```